# Mapping abstract class with mapStruct

Tags: spring, mapstruct

I have a project where I have a `Library` entity which contains a field `media` of type `Media`. `Media` is an abstract class which is implemented by a class `Image` and a class `Video`.

I also have a dto `LibraryDto` with a field `media` of type `MediaDto`. `MediaDto` contains a field whose value can be either `"image"` or `"video"`. My question is : how can I tell mapstruct to instantiate either a `Image` class or a `Video` class based on the value of the `type` field of `MediaDto`?

Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, first time I misunderstood your question.

You can create object factory method which instantiate the `Media` based on the `type` field like this:

```java
@Mapper
public interface LibraryMapper {
    Library libraryDtoToLibrary(LibraryDto libraryDto);

    Media mediaDtoToMedia(MediaDto mediaDto);

    @ObjectFactory
    default Media createMedia(MediaDto mediaDto) {
        if ("image".equals(mediaDto.getType())) {
            return new Image();
        } else if ("video".equals(mediaDto.getType())) {
            return new Video();
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown media type.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup this is the way to do it. Additionally I would annotate the non default methods with `@Named` so that you can reuse the mapper